# Partition with select distinct

Tags: sql-server

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
  StudentName   Course Studentmailid          Score
    Student1       A   student1@gmail.com.     80
    Student1       A   student1@gmail.com.     75
    Student2       A   student2@gmail.com.     70
    Student1       B   student2@gmail.com.     70
```

Now I want records 1,3,4.Basically the first occurance of the student in each Course

I have my query as

```
select distinct StudentName,Course, Studentmailid,Score fromStudentTable group by Course
```

and it throws an error.What would I have to tweak the query as to get the desired output

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @mkRabbani records 1,3 and 4

Comment: Why would you return row 3? both it and row 1 and in the same course, A.

Comment: @Mureinik row 3 is a different student

Comment: Is there any column to order results?

Comment: @mkRabbani no there is not

Answer (score 0):

Hope it help.

```
;with cte as (
  select StudentName,Course, Studentmailid,Score, Row_Number() over (partition by StudentName, Course order by StudentName) as Row_Num from StudentTable
)
select * from cte where Row_Num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a column to define first item from multiple rows. Other wise there is no guaranty that you will get the same output every time. Following is a sample where I order by NULL, which will return record on normal order. But this will not always return the same result.

You need a column with values to order all records. You can then simply replace the ordering part in WINDOW function with your column.

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a734d38721d6bfc7d39559613c444677)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StudentName, Course ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
    -- ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) is basically to keep data as it is now in the table
    -- But there is no guaranty that it will order data in same order always
    FROM your_table
)A
WHERE RN=1
```